# No taskbar icon for application

Tags: vb.net, icons, taskbar

So I have this application I have made in VB. The problem is that when I start it it does not show up in my taskbar. It only shows up if I maximize another window infront of it and then minimize it. Also it has the basic VB icon even though I changed the icon in the properties.

There is no relevant code for this issue.

Comment: What is the value of the form's `ShowInTaskbar` property? Have you changed the icon in the application settings or in the form's property?

Comment: I set ShowInTaskbar to True but it didn't make a difference, I set the Icon in the Application Settings.

Comment: The icon in the application settings defines which Icon is used for the executable. Adjust the `.Icon` property of the form itself to change it there. At least one problem down ;-) The other is hard to say without more details. Try to provide some screenshots and a detailed walkthrough on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here you go, I created a video that demonstrates it. /watch?v=eKzTT-96k1g

Comment: In your video you have selected the Formskin usercontrol (I guess it's that one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24942/Adding-custom-skins-for-Forms-in-VB-Net). This is just a control on the form like any button. Select the underlying form through the combobox at the top of the Properties dialog (where it says Formskin1 in your video). There you have the icon property. Also include more details in your question: You are using many controls like the Awesonium package, the custom skin and so on. This stuff often goes very deep into the WinAPI. Include all these details in your question!

Comment: I see, I didn't know you could do that, thanks! I managed to set the Icon but it still will not show up in the taskbar on launch. Sorry for the very late reply.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thing; no icon was showing in the taskbar. I had to go into Task Manager and Switch To the program to get it to show. I could ' maximize another window in front of it and then minimize it as well.' 
Found the solution that worked for me. The 'Main' form did not have anything in the 'text' property because I was doing that and a Ver number in the program. As soon as I put text into the 'text' property, it started working. The problem was only with VB2015. Worked fine in VB2010.